# +[NSURL URLWithString:] returning nil

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, nsurl

I use this code to load a `UIImage` from a `URL`:

```
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://testwebsite.com/image.png"];
  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

but I'm stuck at a `URL` that looks like this one :
`http://www.testwebsite.com/getFile?userID=123`
this works fine in the browser but returns nil in the `imageData` variable above.

how can I load the image from such an obscured `URL`  (i.e. from a `URL` that does not show off the file name but rather redirects to the image file) ?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for some weird reason I have to use :
`[NSURL URLWithString:[urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

when I create the `URL` and this solved the issue.

Comment: If `+URLWithString:` returns `nil`, it's because you've passed it a malformed string. It's worth trying to figure out what about the string is invalid first, rather than blindly chucking in a call to `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

Answer (score 2):

`NSData initWithContentsOfURL:` returns `nil` if the data cannot be loaded (i.e. if you get a HTTP error code).

Chances are the URL you point to has some referrer blocker or cookie requirement that prevents its use from within your app (just one suggestion of the problem).

I recommend you look at using the following variant instead:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataReadingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

And pay attention to the value of `errorPtr` in case the return value is nil.

For example:

```
NSError *error;
NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/notfound"]
    options:0 error:&error];
if(imageData == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Got %u bytes", imageData.length);
}
```

You can see the following error:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0xa881c20 {NSURL=http://example.com/notfound}
```

Comment: i traced down my code, and found that [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]; returns nil, although there was an available urlStr (like this one http://www.testwebsite.com/getFile?userID=123 ) .. but why does it return nil ?

Comment: I have to use [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 and this solved the issue, i will post it as an answer soon.

Comment: `-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:]` does not care about HTTP status codes, or at least isn't documented to. The URL loading system in general leaves status code checking up to clients

Comment: @MikeAbdullah I failed to find any detailed documentation at all about this method (which, as others have pointed out, should be avoided anyway). Where did you find the documentation about this? (I resorted to trial and error)

Comment: I'm going on the basis that `NSURLConnection` will cheerfully return data to clients, regardless of the HTTP status code. `NSData`'s URL loading is based atop that, and so any status code handling it will have to add in itself

Answer (score 0):

If you load the image like that it's blocking the main thread and leaving your application unresponsive and I'm not sure if the initWithContentsOfURL: method is handling redirects at all if that is the issue... You can create another class (ImageFetcher for example) that uses NSURLConnection and implements the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. Using the connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse: method from the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate you can handle redirects and in the connection:didReceiveData: method you can append the received data to a NSMutableData (it's not guaranteed that you receive all the data in one go). Furthermore you don't have to wait for the connection to finish or download any data if you implement the connection:didReceiveResponse: method and check if the response is indicating an error and in the connectionDidFinishLoading: method you can call another method to update your image view (or call the delegate of the ImageFetcher class with the appropriate data to update the image view).

Comment: Or simply use library like AFNetworking, which will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Yeah, that works too... way better than synchronous loading anyway.

Comment: the problem is not with synchronous or hanging the UI, the problem is with the URL itself

Answer (score 0):

NSURL URLWithString:@"" will return nil if the URL does not conform to RFC 2396 and they must be escaped

If you read through [rfc2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) in the link you will get loads of details

A great site I found for checking where the offending character is, choose the path option for URL

http://www.websitedev.de/temp/rfc2396-check.html.gz